# BadRequest when calling ProcessUserAuthorization after requesting "plus.login" scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

I have problems while updating code to new scope. Currently I use `userinfo.profile` and everything works Ok.

According to [Google+ OAuth 2.0 scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth?hl=en#scopes) new `plus.me` scope allows application to know who user is, and `plus.login` also gives additional access (to age, language, circles, ...).

If I replace `userinfo.profile` with `plus.me` - everything works Ok: method `WebServerClient.RequestUserAuthorization` authorizes user and `ProcessUserAuthorization` gives me a token.

But if I ask `plus.login` scope instead - Google adds additional query parameters to my callback and next call to `WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization` fails , because implementation uses current rul to make new `redirect_url`, striping "known" parameters and leaving "new unknown" Google parameters. his `redirect_url` doesn't match on registered in Google Api Console and Google server returns 400 response.

Here is success response from authorization with `plus.me` scope (from NetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel log):

```
Incoming HTTP request: GET http://localhost:40004/Me/LoginComplete?from=Google&state=TWXf6Zq3XYSlwyfCDt3GiQ&code=4/qC_KeuiykcVm1sayIyEdnBjiklxz.AoMfk5TqaXQcsNf4jSVKMpY-GxwThAI

After binding element processing, the received EndUserAuthorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse (2.0) message is: 
    code: 4/qC_KeuiykcVm1sayIyEdnBjiklxz.AoMfk5TqaXQcsNf4jSVKMpY-GxwThAI
    state: TWXf6Zq3XYSlwyfCDt3GiQ
    from: Google
```

And here is (success) authorization response with `plus.login` scope:

```
Incoming HTTP request: GET http://localhost:40004/Me/LoginComplete?from=Google&state=26R-O3YN6u3-5EKIlJzFFw&code=4/zOoeVq8vec068x2-CyPq4PjPNtRT.osemzp8Zl7sQsNf4jSVKMpbcmWQThAI&authuser=0&prompt=consent&session_state=27ca4bd2e70d0721bc1fa781b900a558e59fe4c7..d409

After binding element processing, the received EndUserAuthorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse (2.0) message is: 
    code: 4/zOoeVq8vec068x2-CyPq4PjPNtRT.osemzp8Zl7sQsNf4jSVKMpbcmWQThAI
    state: 26R-O3YN6u3-5EKIlJzFFw
    from: Google
    authuser: 0
    prompt: consent
    session_state: 27ca4bd2e70d0721bc1fa781b900a558e59fe4c7..d409
```

Call for token (for `plus.me` scope) will be successful:

```
Prepared outgoing AccessTokenAuthorizationCodeRequestC (2.0) message for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: 
    code: 4/qC_KeuiykcVm1sayIyEdnBjiklxz.AoMfk5TqaXQcsNf4jSVKMpY-GxwThAI
    redirect_uri: http://localhost:40004/Me/LoginComplete?from=Google
    grant_type: authorization_code
    client_id: 175802076419.apps.googleusercontent.com
    client_secret: ********
```

But with `plus.login` scope 3 new parameters (authuser, prompt, session_state) are transferred to `redirect_url` param:

```
Prepared outgoing AccessTokenAuthorizationCodeRequestC (2.0) message for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: 
    code: 4/zOoeVq8vec068x2-CyPq4PjPNtRT.osemzp8Zl7sQsNf4jSVKMpbcmWQThAI
    redirect_uri: http://localhost:40004/Me/LoginComplete?from=Google&authuser=0&prompt=consent&session_state=27ca4bd2e70d0721bc1fa781b900a558e59fe4c7..d409
    grant_type: authorization_code
    client_id: 175802076419.apps.googleusercontent.com
    client_secret: ********
```

And as soon as this redirect_url does not match registered I receive error:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token returned 400 BadRequest: Bad Request
```

[OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2) says that params `code` and `state` are required in authorization response and says noting about adding other parameters. But it also says that

> The client MUST ignore unrecognized response parameters

Does this mean that this is DNOA issue and not Google one?

May be DNOA must add nullable responseUri parameter to ProcessUserAuthorization and use it instead of guessing from current url...

What's the easiest workaround (except using Google library)?

Update:

Here is original request for /oauth

```
Prepared outgoing EndUserAuthorizationRequestC (2.0) message for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth: 
    client_id: 175802076419.apps.googleusercontent.com
    redirect_uri: http://localhost:40004/Me/LoginComplete?from=Google
    state: TWXf6Zq3XYSlwyfCDt3GiQ
    scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
    response_type: code
```

Comment: What does your first URL that triggers the flow to accounts.google.com/o/oauth look like?

Comment: First "login" url is /Me/Login. It contains POST form, and server redirect user to appropriate provider based on form content.

Comment: I added second parameter to `ProcessUserAuthorization` - and call succeeded. I created pull request #313 on DNOA github repo.

Comment: Don't need your URL, we to see the URL and the parameters that first hits accounts.google.com/o/oauth prior to returning to your login page.

Comment: Oh sorry. Updated post with request details.